# Can I extend a blade.php that already extends a blade.php for Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

As said in the title I get an error "View cannot be found" when I try to extend a layout/view that already extends another layout/view. I may be confusing layout and view. Am I allowed to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Yes, you can. Your error is caused by something else. Try to figure out what the reason is or update the question with your code and maybe someone will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have be careful with your folder structure for example:

/*----- views/layouts/base.blade.php -----*/

```
<h1>Hey there</h1>
@yield('section1)
```

then your first child should be:

/*----- views/childs/child1.blade.php -----*/

```
@extends('layouts.base')
@section('section1')
    <p>this is section 1 on child</p>
@stop
@yield('section2')
```

after, the grandchild:

/*----- views/grandchilds/grandchild1.blade.php -----*/

```
@extends('childs.child1')
@section('section2')
    <p>this is section 2 on granchild</p>
@stop
```

finally you can call the grand child in controller like this:

/*----- ../MyController.php ----*/

```
...
return view('grandchilds.grandchild1');
...
```